# how to validate changes with vscode for deployment

Tags: vs-code

We have been storing all of our code in a github.

I am able to push it against sandboxes and it deploys. How would you go about validating the force-app against production to see if the whole thing would deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do so with the UI, you must use a terminal command. For example:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy  -c -w 100 -p force-app -l RunLocalTests -u production-alias-or-username
```

Where `-c` is a "check-only" deployment, `-w 100` waits up to 100 minutes for tests to run, `-p` is the file path for the source, `-l RunLocalTests` runs all unpackaged unit tests (required for production deployments), and `-u` is the username to deploy with.

I suggest you check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) for all possible options.